# NodeJS: win-version-info return only FileVersion

Tags: node.js, electron, filesystems

I need some help with returning the FileVersion of a file from a specific path.
I'm using win-version-info which return all the info of the file, but I don't know the syntax for returning just the FileVersion value as a string in a variable.
Tried searching for this but couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated.

```
const vi = require('win-version-info')
const path = require('path');

SAMPLE_PATH = "C:\\Personal\\MyFolder\\MyFile.dll";

const MyFileVersion = ???  <-----???? Only FileVersion Value

console.log(MyFileVersion)
```

Comment: `const MyFileVersion = vi("C:/path/to/file").FileVersion`? That are absolute basics... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Thank you! It is what I needed. Sorry for the noob question.